# Oracle query running indefinitely

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that is somewhat running indefinitely, I might be going in circles here but it doesn't give me an error, just continuously runs.

#### Query

```
WITH calendar AS (
  SELECT dt
  FROM (
    SELECT TRUNC(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(&month || '/01/' || &year, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) - ROWNUM + 1) AS dt
    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 31
  )
  WHERE dt >= TRUNC(TO_DATE(&month || '/01/' || &year, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM')
  ORDER BY dt ASC
)

SELECT
  cal.dt,
  (
    SELECT NVL(SUM(rd.rate_value), 0.00)
    FROM cage_dates cd
    LEFT JOIN cages c ON c.id = cd.cage_id
    LEFT JOIN rent_item ri ON ri.id = c.rent_item_id
    LEFT JOIN rate_dates rd ON rd.rent_item_id = c.rent_item_id
    WHERE c.group_id = 123
    AND c.room_id = 456
    AND (
      LOWER(c.cage_use) NOT IN ('created in error', 'prod setup')
      OR c.cage_use IS NULL
    )
    AND ri.display_name NOT LIKE '% BR'
    AND TRUNC(cd.added) <= cal.dt
    AND (
      CASE
        WHEN cd.removed IS NOT NULL AND TRUNC(cd.removed) >= cal.dt THEN 1
        WHEN cd.removed IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END = 1
    )
    AND TRUNC(rd.effective_on) <= cal.dt
    AND (
      CASE
        WHEN rd.effective_until IS NOT NULL AND TRUNC(rd.effective_until) >= cal.dt THEN 1
        WHEN rd.effective_until IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END = 1
    )
  ) AS per_diem
FROM calendar cal
ORDER BY cal.dt ASC
```

When I change `cal.dt` to `TO_DATE('10/25/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')` it gives me the correct SUM of the all the rates for that day but attaches it to all the days like so:

```
dt          per_diem
--------------------
10/01/2017      1.19
10/02/2017      1.19
...
10/31/2017      1.19
```

Whereas I want something like:

```
dt          per_diem
--------------------
10/01/2017         0
10/02/2017      1.19
10/03/2017      2.52
...
10/31/2017      0.67
```

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: are you trying to create a "running sum"? why not just use `SUM(rd.rate_value) over( order by cal.dt)` ? [you can remove the redundant order by in the cte]

Comment: @Used_By_Already No, the sum isn't a running value. It's the sum of all the per diems that needs to be charged for that day depending on how many cages are used that day. I'll take a look at your solution later - I need to attend a meeting in a couple minutes.

Comment: Are &year and &month defined?

Comment: @1010 Those are just being passed as parameters. `&month = 10` and `&year = 2017` is an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would move the subquery into a join, like this:

```
WITH calendar AS (
  SELECT dt
  FROM (
    SELECT TRUNC(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(&month || '/01/' || &year, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) - ROWNUM + 1) AS dt
    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 31
  )
  WHERE dt >= TRUNC(TO_DATE(&month || '/01/' || &year, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM')
)
SELECT cal.dt, NVL(SUM(rd.rate_value), 0.00)
FROM Calendar cal
LEFT JOIN cage_dates cd ON TRUNC(cd.added) = cal.dt
LEFT JOIN cages c ON c.id = cd.cage_id
LEFT JOIN rent_item ri ON ri.id = c.rent_item_id
LEFT JOIN rate_dates rd ON rd.rent_item_id = c.rent_item_id
WHERE c.group_id = 123
AND c.room_id = 456
AND (
  LOWER(c.cage_use) NOT IN ('created in error', 'prod setup')
  OR c.cage_use IS NULL
)
AND ri.display_name NOT LIKE '% BR'
AND (
  CASE
    WHEN cd.removed IS NOT NULL AND TRUNC(cd.removed) >= cal.dt THEN 1
    WHEN cd.removed IS NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END = 1
)
AND TRUNC(rd.effective_on) <= cal.dt
AND (
  CASE
    WHEN rd.effective_until IS NOT NULL AND TRUNC(rd.effective_until) >= cal.dt THEN 1
    WHEN rd.effective_until IS NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END = 1
GROUP  BY cal.dt
```

But I am not sure what you are actually attempting with the `TRUNC(cd.added) <= cal.dt` at first thought is was a running sum, but perhaps you are trying to make a value appear on every day?

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Care to explain why my original query runs indefinitely though? I would still prefer to have a subquery instead of doing a join because I need to do this again as a separate column but for `AND ri.display_name LIKE '% BR'`. If I join this twice, the sums for the first join gets multiplied by the number of rows in the second join.

Comment: Right now my solution is to execute 2 queries. One for this and another one for `AND ri.display_name LIKE '% BR'` just so they don't multiply each other. I would prefer to just run a single query.

Comment: That can be done using "conditional aggregates" add this to your select clause `SUM (CASE WHEN ri.display_name LIKE '% BR' THEN rd.rate_value else 0 end)`